Near Analysis with GEODESIC method, the feature classes aren't being recognized
I have postal codes and bus stop location, I need to find out the nearest bus stops from postal code location. I am applying GEODESIC distance method in near analysis.
import arcpy as ap

# Set workspace environment
ap.env.workspace = "D:/SadiaChowdhury/Data analysis/Data Cleaning"
ap.env.overwriteOutput = True

in_features = "D:/SadiaChowdhury/Data analysis/Data Cleaning/postal.21/postal.21.shp"
near_features= "D:/SadiaChowdhury/Data analysis/Data Cleaning/Transit Routes Final/HSR_Bus_Stops/HSR_Bus_Stops.shp"
search_radius = "400 Meters"
location = "LOCATION"
angle = "ANGLE"
method = "GEODESIC"
distance_unit = "Meters"
ap.analysis.Near(in_features, near_features, {search_radius}, {location}, {angle}, {method}, {distance_unit})

But it is showing following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\SadiaChowdhury\Data analysis\Data Cleaning\Geodsic_04.06.24.py", line 18, in <module>
    ap.analysis.Near(in_features, near_features, {search_radius}, {location}, {angle}, {method}, {distance_unit})
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 1888, in Near
    raise e
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 1885, in Near
    retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.Near_analysis(*gp_fixargs((in_features, near_features, search_radius, location, angle, method, field_names), True)))
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 512, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool


When you call your near tool, do not put your parameters inside {}.

Thanks for the comment, I removed the second bracket. But it is showing the same :(

Get rid of all the bracers, in the tool description they signify optional parameters and have no place in your code. Optional parameters can be skipped if you use the parameter name like method = method... on your syntax. Also it's a really good idea to make your variables not exactly the same as the keyword, I suggest camel case https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case for your variables as almost all keywords are lower case; Python is a case sensitive language so method is not the same as Method, that way you can easily tell what's a keyword and what's a variable.
